# how to given link of custom Blog page on click button in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to redirect on my blog page after click on button

This is my code:

```
<div id="blog_button"> <a href="<?php echo site_url('Blog');?>"><input type="button" value="Blog"></a>
```

How to use site_url()? How to reach on my blog page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url

Inside the site_url brackets you add the path you wish to append to your link. For example, site_url() results to http://www.example.com
while site_url('blog') results to http://www.example.com/blog

Also, you missed a closing div in your code.

```
<div id="blog_button">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('Blog');?>"><input type="button" value="Blog"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help .. my site url is on local host is :http://192.168.1.4:8081/Pradeep/Global_Tech_Support/wordpress/ and i wants to add blog button on header page then plz tell me the exat code for it and how to use site_url('path ') beacuase i am new here on wordpress

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that site_url will always return "the site url for the current site (where the WordPress core files reside)". Therefore, site_url('blog') for you will return "http://192.168.1.4:8081/Pradeep/Global_Tech_Support/wordpress/blog"

Comment: Thanks Stack Overflow
yes i have done it now

the exat code is 

 <div id="blog_button">

  <a href="<?php echo site_url('../wordpress/blog/'); ?>
"><input type="button" value="Blog" /></a>
 
  </div>

Comment: No, that is wrong. site_url() by default IS your site url. Inside the brackets, you add the page you want to add after the URL.